# What is causing the segmentation fault in this code?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, segmentation-fault

I am getting a segmentation fault in my code, but I'm having trouble tracking down the problem. This is the section of the code where the segmentation fault seems to take place:

```
for (i = 0; i < ROBOTCOUNT; i++)
{
    ROS_INFO("Test 1");
    Robot r;
    robotList.push_back(&r);
    ROS_INFO("Test 2");
}
```

When run this prints only the following two lines

```
Test 1
Test 2
```

Based off the print lines it seems like the code only loops once and then a segmentation fault occurs.

What could be causing this?

Comment: What is `ROS_INFO` ? is `robotList` vector of `Robot` ?

Comment: It's for printing in ROS

Comment: Is there a good reason for robotList to store pointers to Robot objects and not the objects themselves? i.e., would it make sense to change `vector<Robot*>` to `vector<Robot>` (or list<Robot*>, or whatever)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saving an address of local variable which is destroyed in your list.

```
for (i = 0; i < ROBOTCOUNT; i++)
{
    ROS_INFO("Test 1");
    Robot r; <== local variable
    robotList.push_back(&r); <== save address of local
    ROS_INFO("Test 2");
}  <== r is destroyed
```

So it's likely that you are accessing the deleted memory later

Use `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Robot>>`:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Robot>> v;
std::shared_ptr<Robot> ptr( new Robot() );
v.push_back(ptr)
```

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for the answer. Is there a way to make it so r is not destroyed? Or a different way of creating objects in a loop to store the addresses in a vector?

Comment: But that will not cause the segfault. Segfault is where he is accessing the items. @Jigglypuff do Robot* r = new Robot;

Comment: @Jigglypuff: I added an example