# Pointer traversal issue in overloaded function for Doubly Linked List [C++]

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, c++17

I'm implementing a doubly linked list in C++ and have created two functions for adding a node to the right end with different signature as shown below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;

class LinkedList {
private:
  int value;
  LinkedList *next;
  LinkedList *prev;

public:
  LinkedList(int const &x, LinkedList *nextptr = nullptr,
             LinkedList *prevptr = nullptr)
      : value(x), next(nextptr), prev(prevptr){};
  
  int getValue() const { return value; }
  
  bool hasNext() const { return next ? true : false; }
  
  bool hasPrev() const { return prev ? true : false; }
  
  void setNext(LinkedList *node) { next = node; }
  
  void setPrev(LinkedList *node) { prev = node; }
  
  LinkedList *getNext() const { return next; }
  
  LinkedList *getPrev() const { return prev; }
  
  void addNode(LinkedList *node) {
    LinkedList *walker = this;
    while (walker->getNext()) {
      walker = walker->getNext();
    }
    walker->setNext(node);
    node->setPrev(walker);
  }
  
  void addNode(int x) {
    LinkedList newNode = LinkedList(x);
    LinkedList *node = &newNode;
    LinkedList *walker = this;
    while (walker->getNext()) {
      walker = walker->getNext();
    }
    walker->setNext(node);
    node->setPrev(walker);
  } // why does using this lead to an infinite loop?

  void printL2R() {
    LinkedList *walker = this;
    while (walker) {
      cout << "<-" << walker->getValue() << "->";
      walker = walker->getNext();
    }
    cout << "\n";
  }

};

int main() {
  LinkedList l = LinkedList(10);
  LinkedList l1 = LinkedList(20);
  LinkedList l2 = LinkedList(30);
  LinkedList l3 = LinkedList(40);

  l.addNode(&l1);
  l.addNode(&l2);
  l.addNode(&l3);
  l.printL2R(); // printL2R works fine till here.
  l.addNode(20);
  l.printL2R(); // runs infinitely
  return 0;
}
```

The expected output for the code (which works fine if I just use the `addNode(LinkedList* node)` function is:

```
<-10-><-20-><-30-><-40->
```

However, when I use the `addNode(int x)` function I get an infinite loop that looks like this:

```
<-10-><-20-><-30-><-40-><-20-><-20-><-20-><-20->...on loop
```

It would be really grateful if someone could help me understand why this happens even though both the functions are being implemented in the same way(?).
Thanks.

Comment: IMHO, your `addNode(int x)` should create a new node then call `addNode(LinkedList * node)`.  This should reduce the code so that insertion only occurs in one place.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, thanks for replying!
I changed the code as you suggested.
However, the error still persists.

Comment: Your code is dangerous in several ways. Your immediate problem is that `LinkedList *node = &newNode;` (which is then added to the data structure) is taking the address of a variable on the stack in a frame that is about to be ended. You're also not thinking about memory management or ownership. You should look up the "Rule of 5" (formerly Rule of 3).

Comment: The infinite loop is definitely caused by setting the next node of the list to a local variable that immediately gets destroyed - the memory is then used for something else: the variable declaration in the print function.  Memory corruption can do anything.

Comment: Related: [What is causing the segmentation fault in this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016215)

Answer (score -1):

You should write :

```
LinkedList* node = new LinkedList(x);
```

instead of this :

```
LinkedList newNode = LinkedList(x); 
LinkedList *node = &newNode;
```